# Tell Hibernate to create a new table just for one entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I've added new class into my project. If I use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` property it recreates tables for the whole project, but I need Hibernate to create and execute **DDL** just for this new class.

Comment: Both answers are correct `update` will work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to use `update` value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property. This way, hibernate will only update the schema without recreating it entirely.

So if you want to catch the table ddl statement, drop your database, unmap your entity and let hibernate create the whole schema without your entity. Later, enable the entity map, and run hibernate again.

But, instead using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property, I will recommend you to try liquibase, this is a much more powerful way. You can see a demo project [here](https://github.com/malaguna/casiopea)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use update statement

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>             

            or

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

i hope this will help :)